# Query Mongo Collection w/Compound Key

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a compound key:

```
db.stuff.insert( {"_id":{"aid":"123","brand":"acme"},"name":"Greg"} )
```

The compound key ensures uniqueness in a multi-tenant environment.  For this application the order being constant for BSON is fine.

My question is this:  Can I find all the 'stuff' with brand = "acme" (i.e. use one part of the compound key in a query)?  If it's possible will it utilize the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use a simple `find()`:

```
db.stuff.find({"_id.brand" : "acme"});
```